# Div takes up entire height of container yet stays at the bottom

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with one of my div's specifically **.mid-content**. It's taking up the entire height of my outer div **.main-content** but I want it to be below my other two inner divs **.posts** and **.sidebars**. Instead it's to the left side of **.sidebars**.

I tried making the display of the **.mid-content** div into a block yet the problem persists. I also tried playing around with the overflow settings in the container div it causes the border of my header to get removed.

Here's my code

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My First Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="header">
        <ul class="navigation-bar">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="main-content">
        <div class="posts top-buffer">
          <div class="post">
            <h1>A Post About Something</h1>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed efficitur urna id mauris laoreet, at dictum ligula tincidunt. Sed eu facilisis nibh. Vivamus a molestie erat, ornare interdum tellus. Maecenas fermentum molestie augue a sollicitudin. Pellentesque feugiat ipsum ut orci consequat tempor. Quisque a urna aliquam, semper lorem sed, venenatis massa. Ut mauris dui, blandit at erat nec, pulvinar eleifend tellus. Donec laoreet lorem ac sodales molestie.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed efficitur urna id mauris laoreet, at dictum ligula tincidunt. Sed eu facilisis nibh. Vivamus a molestie erat, ornare interdum tellus. Maecenas fermentum molestie augue a sollicitudin. Pellentesque feugiat ipsum ut orci consequat tempor. Quisque a urna aliquam, semper lorem sed, venenatis massa. Ut mauris dui, blandit at erat nec, pulvinar eleifend tellus. Donec laoreet lorem ac sodales molestie.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed efficitur urna id mauris laoreet, at dictum ligula tincidunt. Sed eu facilisis nibh. Vivamus a molestie erat, ornare interdum tellus. Maecenas fermentum molestie augue a sollicitudin. Pellentesque feugiat ipsum ut orci consequat tempor. Quisque a urna aliquam, semper lorem sed, venenatis massa. Ut mauris dui, blandit at erat nec, pulvinar eleifend tellus. Donec laoreet lorem ac sodales molestie.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed efficitur urna id mauris laoreet, at dictum ligula tincidunt. Sed eu facilisis nibh. Vivamus a molestie erat, ornare interdum tellus. Maecenas fermentum molestie augue a sollicitudin. Pellentesque feugiat ipsum ut orci consequat tempor. Quisque a urna aliquam, semper lorem sed, venenatis massa. Ut mauris dui, blandit at erat nec, pulvinar eleifend tellus. Donec laoreet lorem ac sodales molestie.
            </p>
          </div> 
        </div>

        <div class="sidebars top-buffer">
          <div class="sidebar">
            <h1>Sidebar One</h1>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed efficitur urna id mauris laoreet, at dictum ligula tincidunt. Sed eu facilisis nibh. Vivamus a molestie erat, ornare interdum tellus. Maecenas fermentum molestie augue a sollicitudin. Pellentesque feugiat ipsum ut orci consequat tempor. Quisque a urna aliquam, semper lorem sed, venenatis massa. Ut mauris dui, blandit at erat nec, pulvinar eleifend tellus. Donec laoreet lorem ac sodales molestie.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed efficitur urna id mauris laoreet, at dictum ligula tincidunt. Sed eu facilisis nibh. Vivamus a molestie erat, ornare interdum tellus. Maecenas fermentum molestie augue a sollicitudin. Pellentesque feugiat ipsum ut orci consequat tempor. Quisque a urna aliquam, semper lorem sed, venenatis massa. Ut mauris dui, blandit at erat nec, pulvinar eleifend tellus. Donec laoreet lorem ac sodales molestie.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mid-content">
          <h1>
            This Should be below everything
          </h1>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: futura;
}

body {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #777777;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.navigation-bar {
    height: 80px;
    width: 80%;

}

.navigation-bar > ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.navigation-bar > li {
    width: 20%; 
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}

.navigation-bar > li > a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    line-height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation-bar a:hover, .navigation-bar a:active, .active {
    background-color: #ff8989;
}

.main-content {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.top-buffer {
    margin-top: 2%;
}

.posts {
    width: 55%;
    float: left;
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding: 2% 4%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 4%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #ffc893;

}

.sidebars {
    width: 26%;
    float: right;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 2% 3%;
    background-color: #b5ffb2;
}

.mid-content {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the clear:both style to your .mid-content class:

```
.mid-content {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    clear: both;
}
```

That will force the div below both of the columns above it.

Also, change the display from block to inline-block and you can apply margin and padding to the div.

https://plnkr.co/edit/wJp9m0RKxuvAjn71rkFH?p=preview

Comment: Updated with plnkr to demonstrate.

Comment: This fixed the problem but is it that when I do a margin-top of 20px for example, the positioning of the div: .mid-content stays the same?

Comment: Change the display from block to inline-block and you can apply margin and padding to the div.

Comment: Thank you that fixed it..I'm pretty terrible at choosing best answer but since you also followed with that second question of mine I'll give it to you

Answer (score 3):

Just use `clear: both` on `.mid-content` div. check updated snippet below

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: futura;
}

body {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #777777;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.navigation-bar {
    height: 80px;
    width: 80%;

}

.navigation-bar > ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.navigation-bar > li {
    width: 20%; 
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}

.navigation-bar > li > a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    line-height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation-bar a:hover, .navigation-bar a:active, .active {
    background-color: #ff8989;
}

.main-content {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.top-buffer {
    margin-top: 2%;
}

.posts {
    width: 55%;
    float: left;
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding: 2% 4%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 4%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #ffc893;

}

.sidebars {
    width: 26%;
    float: right;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 2% 3%;
    background-color: #b5ffb2;
}

.mid-content {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="header">
    <ul class="navigation-bar">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="posts top-buffer">
      <div class="post">
        <h1>A Post About Something</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed efficitur urna id mauris laoreet, at dictum ligula tincidunt. Sed eu facilisis nibh. Vivamus a molestie erat, ornare interdum tellus. Maecenas fermentum molestie augue a sollicitudin. Pellentesque feugiat ipsum ut orci consequat tempor. Quisque a urna aliquam, semper lorem sed, venenatis massa. Ut mauris dui, blandit at erat nec, pulvinar eleifend tellus. Donec laoreet lorem ac sodales molestie.
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed efficitur urna id mauris laoreet, at dictum ligula tincidunt. Sed eu facilisis nibh. Vivamus a molestie erat, ornare interdum tellus. Maecenas fermentum molestie augue a sollicitudin. Pellentesque feugiat ipsum ut orci consequat tempor. Quisque a urna aliquam, semper lorem sed, venenatis massa. Ut mauris dui, blandit at erat nec, pulvinar eleifend tellus. Donec laoreet lorem ac sodales molestie.
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed efficitur urna id mauris laoreet, at dictum ligula tincidunt. Sed eu facilisis nibh. Vivamus a molestie erat, ornare interdum tellus. Maecenas fermentum molestie augue a sollicitudin. Pellentesque feugiat ipsum ut orci consequat tempor. Quisque a urna aliquam, semper lorem sed, venenatis massa. Ut mauris dui, blandit at erat nec, pulvinar eleifend tellus. Donec laoreet lorem ac sodales molestie.
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed efficitur urna id mauris laoreet, at dictum ligula tincidunt. Sed eu facilisis nibh. Vivamus a molestie erat, ornare interdum tellus. Maecenas fermentum molestie augue a sollicitudin. Pellentesque feugiat ipsum ut orci consequat tempor. Quisque a urna aliquam, semper lorem sed, venenatis massa. Ut mauris dui, blandit at erat nec, pulvinar eleifend tellus. Donec laoreet lorem ac sodales molestie.
        </p>
      </div> 
    </div>

    <div class="sidebars top-buffer">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <h1>Sidebar One</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed efficitur urna id mauris laoreet, at dictum ligula tincidunt. Sed eu facilisis nibh. Vivamus a molestie erat, ornare interdum tellus. Maecenas fermentum molestie augue a sollicitudin. Pellentesque feugiat ipsum ut orci consequat tempor. Quisque a urna aliquam, semper lorem sed, venenatis massa. Ut mauris dui, blandit at erat nec, pulvinar eleifend tellus. Donec laoreet lorem ac sodales molestie.
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed efficitur urna id mauris laoreet, at dictum ligula tincidunt. Sed eu facilisis nibh. Vivamus a molestie erat, ornare interdum tellus. Maecenas fermentum molestie augue a sollicitudin. Pellentesque feugiat ipsum ut orci consequat tempor. Quisque a urna aliquam, semper lorem sed, venenatis massa. Ut mauris dui, blandit at erat nec, pulvinar eleifend tellus. Donec laoreet lorem ac sodales molestie.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mid-content">
      <h1>
        This Should be below everything
      </h1>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```